# Compiling a gcc library with 1.0 in name from powershell

Tags: powershell, compiler-errors, compilation, mingw, linkage

I am trying to compile a project using the libusb-1.0 library. When i compile from cmd with the following command

`gcc -g main.c -o test.exe -lusb-1.0`

my program compiles just fine. However if I try to use the Powershell window inside VSC i get this error

`gcc.exe: error: .0: No such file or directory`

I've run the same code from both terminals.
While I still can compile and run my code, it would be convenient if I could do it from within VSC.
How can i fix this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with (double) quotes around the `-lusb-1.0` parameter.